# Rails 3 redirecting to strange ID after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

trail has_many chapters

chapter belongs_to trail

my routes:

```
resources :trails do
  member do
    resources :chapters do
      member do
        resources :clues
    end
  end
 end
end
```

called from a standard form in new.html view

from my chapters_controller.rb

```
def creat
  @trail = Trail.find(params[:id])
  @chapter = @trail.chapters.build(params[:chapter])
     if @chapter.save
       flash.now[:status] = "Chapter created"
       redirect_to @chapter
     else
       flash.now[:error] = "Name needed"
       render 'new'
     end
end
```

The log which reveals how the trail ID starts out as 1, and then after the create the trail ID is 28 (or the chapter_id).

```
Started POST "/trails/1/chapters" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri May 04 20:31:15 -0700 2012
Processing by ChaptersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create New Chapter", "chapter"=>{"name"=>"", "gate"=>"", "assetkind"=>"url", "description"=>"", "asset"=>""}, "authenticity_token"=>"Puu7EL8yQEsU4/NimBdL6mJRXiXoFTbHb1DSYvFNDgI=", "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"1"}

.
.
.
(3.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/trails/28/chapters/28
```

I expect it to redirect to ..trails/1/chapters/28  ...  when I change the url to reflect the path I expect, the correct page shows with the correct content.

I'm having a number of problems, but I think this might be a clue to help me figure them out.  Is there something wrong with my routes or with my associations?  I kind of restructured my associations and nested them and now I'm having issues.

Much thanks for your time and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are overly specific. You really just need this:

```
resources :trails do
  resources :chapters do
    resources :clues
  end
end
```

And really, you should probably consider whether it's worth it to leave `clues` nested at the third level rather than providing shallow routes.

Also, you will need to hand both objects used to build a nested `chapter` route to the path helper:

```
redirect_to trail_chapter_path(@trail, @chapter)
```

Otherwise it'll only have the ID of the chapter. This is what is causing your trail ID to jump unexpectedly to 28.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept it as the answer by clicking on the checkbox to the left of the question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!